# SIMPLE AJAX CALL and open the page in new tab-loosing post value

Tags: ajax, call, phpword

I am trying to open second page this POST values (id_od_client, reports array, which includes only type of report and id of report). I want to generete report via phpword, but I have problem, that values are not posted. I think, it is due to posts and open page after success lost posted data.
I am trying

```
var url="complete_report.php?Id="+id_client;
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        "id_client": id_client,
        "report_array": report_array,
                            },
        success: function(data){
////not work as expected window.location = url; 
////not work as expected window.open('complete_report.php?Id='+id_client, '_blank');
////not work as expected window.location.href=url;
                    }
                        });
```

if I try in complete_report.php condition if(isset($_POST['id_client])) it not work.
Data are OK, but how to open in in new tab with posted data.If I tried method get and open file beforeSend it worked as expected.
Must be form action added in html form or somethink like that?
I think my issue is loosing POST value because of opening it later. I could be solved by sessions/cookies but it must be solved without that.
Also problem could be that complete_report does not anwering anything, just only create doc file.
I am not able to found the solution.
Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it via adding action="complete_report.php" in html form and adding hidden input field in form(id_client and report_array) and jquery submit function. It works, but I dont know how to made it via simple ajax method (or post...)